# Manipulate a string and return it as html

Tags: javascript, html, regex, reactjs

I have a string coming in from a CMS like this:

MSRP Base Price †

The string is not mutable and I need to replace the † wrapped around superscript tags like this:

```
<sup>†</sup>
```

However, with the str.replace method, I'm using:

```
var superLabel = str.replace(new RegExp('†'), '<sup>†</sup>');
```

superLabel is returning this: MSRP Base Price < sup>†< sup>

Comment: This is not sufficiently clear.  Will the strings always begin "MSRP Base Price"?

Comment: Yes @GeorgeJempty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned React in your question. React will automatically decode your string to avoid XSS attacks.

You need to use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) to set your value.

Example:

```
// Does not work
const string = '<sup>†</sup>';
return <div>{string}</div>;

// Works
const string = '<sup>†</sup>';
return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={string} />;
```

Be careful though and make sure your input is safe.

Comment: I got a "Can only set one of `children` or `props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML`."

from <p className={styles.priceLabel} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.handlePriceLabel(priceLabel)}></p>

Comment: try `<p className={styles.priceLabel} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.handlePriceLabel(priceLabel)} />`

Comment: @klugjo your suggestion led to a correct answer. I just had to return the html like this: return {__html: superLabel} inside this.handlePriceLabel

Answer (score 1):

The following is one way to do what you need except for what's mentioned in the answer accounting for React, which I'm not familiar with.

```
var fromCMSPrefix = 'MSRP Base Price'
var fromCMS = 'MSRP Base Price †';
var superLabel = '<sup>' + fromCMS.substr(fromCMSPrefix.length).trim() + '</sup>';
```

Here's another:

```
var fromCMS = 'MSRP Base Price †';
var superLabel = '<sup>' + fromCMS.replace('MSRP Base Price', '').trim() + '</sup>';
```